# Automating jQuery based bootstrap dropdown using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to list all elements from the bootstrap dropdown and then select a certain value. However, it returns 0 values. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imgSelectButton")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='logoSelectOpt']//li"));
System.out.println(list.size());
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    if (list.get(i).getText().contains("History")){
        list.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

DOM:

```
<div class="logoSelect" style="z-index:1; top:878px;">==$0
 <ul>
  <li class="logoSelectOpt" id="12" onmouseover="jQuery(QWE01Title.activate(this);" onmouseout="jQuery(QWE01Title.deactivate(this);" onmousedown="jQuery(QWE01Title.selectItem(this);" logoColor="#FFF">Facts</li>==0
  <li class="logoSelectOpt" id="12" onmouseover="jQuery(QWE01Title.activate(this);" onmouseout="jQuery(QWE01Title.deactivate(this);" onmousedown="jQuery(QWE01Title.selectItem(this);" logoColor="#FFF">History</li>==0
  <li class="logoSelectOpt" id="12" onmouseover="jQuery(QWE01Title.activate(this);" onmouseout="jQuery(QWE01Title.deactivate(this);" onmousedown="jQuery(QWE01Title.selectItem(this);" logoColor="#FFF">Opinions</li>==0
  <li class="logoSelectOpt" id="12" onmouseover="jQuery(QWE01Title.activate(this);" onmouseout="jQuery(QWE01Title.deactivate(this);" onmousedown="jQuery(QWE01Title.selectItem(this);" logoColor="#FFF">Questions</li>==0
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements are [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) enabled element so to locate the elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("imgSelectButton")).click();
  List<WebElement> list = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.logoSelect > ul li.logoSelectOpt")));
  System.out.println(list.size());
  for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
      if (list.get(i).getText().contains("History")){
          list.get(i).click();
          break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("imgSelectButton")).click();
  List<WebElement> list = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='logoSelect']/ul//li[@class='logoSelectOpt']")));
  System.out.println(list.size());
  for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
      if (list.get(i).getText().contains("History")){
          list.get(i).click();
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: DebanjanB thank you so much for your response. I've tried your methods but is throws a TimeoutExeption.

Comment: @AlexAlex _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations. Check the HTML and traverse upwards and observe if the element is within an <iframe> tag, then you have to switch to the desired `<iframe>` first before clicking the element. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) once

Comment: There was problem with my xpath. I removed the WebDriverWait, used your version of the xpath and it worked! Thank you so much!